# C# SQL Server converting date time error when transferring to another PC

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using VS2012 and SQL Server 2012 as database - it all works fine, but when I transfer it to another laptop which also using VS2012 and SQL Server 2012, I am getting an error in converting date in database to date time here is the code.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr8["Date Added"].toString());
```

The `Date Added` is stored as `VARCHAR(MAX)` but it works well in my pc but when transferred to my laptop it shows an error

> String was not recognized as a valid `DateTime'

[image: results]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Parsing is "culture" specific. You may have culture differences between the two accounts you are using. Any particular reason you felt that All Caps was the right way to title your post?

Comment: One of the **many reasons** why you should use **the most appropriate** datatype - always - and if you have a date and time, **store it as such**, in a `DATETIME2(n)` column (or if you need only the date, no time, then use `DATE`)  - don't just store everything in `VARCHAR` columns because you're too lazy to use other datatypes!

Comment: **The Date Added is stored as VARCHAR(MAX)** There's your problem right there. This is probably the second worst way possible to store date values - the worst one being `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to default cultural setups on your multiple machines. Also see this post: [C# DateTime conversion same culture on different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859779/c-sharp-datetime-conversion-same-culture-on-different-machines) 
Besides I would recommend using TryParse instead of Parse, to handle all these errors properly. For example see the code below, and the version after for a fixed culture:

```
 // First version
    public static bool TryFormat(string dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTime)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateTime))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

// Second version , specifying the cuture as suggested by @Zohar
public static bool TryFormat(string dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTime)
        {
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, culture, style, out dateTime))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Other then the fact that this is not the source of the problem, the `TryParse(string, DateTime)` documentation states:
"The string s is parsed using formatting information in the current DateTimeFormatInfo object, which is supplied implicitly by the current thread culture." - so this overload of `TryParse` depends of the culture settings of the current thread - so if anything, it's better to [the other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: That is a good point. Lets replace the code with this: public static bool TryFormat(string dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTime)
        {
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, culture, style, out dateTime))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }